# Formula to convert State Plane Coordinates to Latitude and Longitude

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, arcgis-rest-api, state-plane

The data I have is in State Plane Coordinates and I need them in regular Latitude and Longitude form. Is there an easy formula to convert them?

ZONE: 3104 (NAD 1983 StatePlane New York Long Island FIPS 3104 Feet)

I'm pulling the data from ArcGIS NYC MapPluto API query [here](http://services5.arcgis.com/GfwWNkhOj9bNBqoJ/ArcGIS/rest/services/MAPPLUTO/FeatureServer/0/query)
eg. Where: bbl = 1000430006 and I'm requesting GeoJSON output.

Is there a way to output the data already converted?

Comment: Ah, put "bbl = 1000430006" in the "Where:" box and hit one of the Query buttons at the bottom. Yes, you can convert from one coordinate system to another with most GIS and most programming languages. If you just have the raw formula you can do it with a desk calculator. What have you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the "Output spatial reference" field to "4326", you'll get the results returned using EPSG:4326 coordinate system, which is the usual lat-long used these days, and is the same system that most GPS units default to.

With "output spatial reference" left blank:

```
# results: 1

OwnerName:  US GOVERNMENT
geometry    Polygon:
Ring0:[981499.81518554687,197022.05780029297],[981381.22521972656,196861.61462402344],[981307.0732421875,196922.38079833984]...2 more...
```

With "output spatial reference" set to 4326:

```
# results: 1

OwnerName:  US GOVERNMENT
geometry    Polygon:
Ring0:[-74.009920968454054,40.707464582669736],[-74.010348637064965,40.7070241663017],[-74.010616117411985,40.707190930767545]...2 more...
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Is there any chance of reversing the order, to get first Latitude then Longitude?

Comment: Not that I can see, but it should be trivial to do in any programming language or database system that you might read the data into.

Comment: Absolutely,I'll need to manipulate the data anyhow. Thanks a lot.